# move_uploaded file:failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/http/upload.php

Tags: php, linux, apache, server, archlinux

I am trying to run a server on ArchLinux, I have apache and PHP running normally, but i can't upload a file with PHP. I have seen many questions of this sort on Stackoverflow and I seem to have used all the suggestions I found, but I still get a

```
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/http/upload.php
```

error.

To be precise

```
Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpZvJK1l' to '/home/administrator/SCRIPTS/tr/solution.cpp' in /srv/http/upload.php on line 20
```

I set the permissions for /tmp/, /home/administrator/SCRIPTS/tr and /srv/http to 777 (I know thats not right, but I am working locally right now and I want to get it working somehow).

Also I set all the owner of these directories to http (that is the user running PHP), but the thing still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some PHP configurations do not allow file access outside the users docroot directory, so you may not have access to /tmp from within PHP.  Try uploading your file(s) to a temp directory within your /home/administrator directory - preferably to a directory that isn't accessible to web browsers (a sibling directory to your docroot).

Comment: I changed the temp dir to /home/temp , but I am still getting the same error. It seems that I am making some idiotic small mistake that I just can't notice

Comment: UPD: All done. I changed the /administrator folder owner to http

Answer (score 0):

give permission to the /tmp dir :

sudo chmod 777 /tmp

Comment: It's not a /tmp problem DO NOT FOLLOW THIS

Comment: If it'll be a /tmp problem, he couldn't create the `/tmp/phpZvJK1l` file.

Answer (score 0):

As an Arch user I have the same issue when I work on web projects.

I'll recommend you to see [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#User_directories) part of the Arch Wiki

> User directories are available by default through http://localhost/~yourusername/ and show the contents of ~/public_html (this can be changed in /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf).

So do to so you have to create the ~/public_html directory then

> You must make sure that your home directory permissions are set properly so that Apache can get there. Your home directory and ~/public_html must be executable for others ("rest of the world"):

```
$ chmod o+x ~
$ chmod o+x ~/public_html
$ chmod -R o+r ~/public_html
```

After that you don't need to put your file under `/srv/http/` you can now use `~/public_html` as development directory.

Comment: @Petr just updated my answer to be more "Arch" oriented :)